# How to generate tiled Geo/Topo JSON?

Tags: tiles, topojson

Are there any command line tools can take a Shapefile or a GeoJSON file and generate a tiled version of them?

Answer (score 1):

From my knowledge, your best option is use Tilestache.
http://tilestache.org/